# Can I make MPV player to pick up any subtitles available in the folder?

Tags: video, subtitle

[GitHub Source Page](https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv)

i'm using this really amazing video player in ubuntu, i just want to make little change in it's behaviour with subtitles (`.srt` files)

**Default Behaviour**

currently MPV shows subtitles which are hard coded in a video file or srt file which is exactly named as the video file, for eg it'll pick up the subtitle file if the name of video file is `video.mkv` and name of the subtitle file is `video.srt` , but it won't pick it up if it's different.

**What I want to achieve**

it should pick up any and all the subtitles which are available in the same folder as the video file, automatically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SMPlayer](http://smplayer.sourceforge.net) is a frontend for various media player programs, defaulting in modern versions to mpv. If you don't mind using it (since you'd be using mpv with some niceties),  it gives this option for selecting subtitles:

[image]

It is available in Ubuntu's repositories, so a `sudo apt-get install smplayer` is enough to get it.

Comment: i tried to stay away from it because GUI looked terrible, but it's highly configurable and I've managed to  make it look more minimalist, thanks for the suggestion, works for me

Comment: @SumeetDeshmukh ah yes, I should have mentioned that the first thing I do when installing it is to go to the Interface settings and change the themes and layout

Comment: that's what I did, it's already growing on me, thanks again

Answer (score 8):

To provide an actual mpv only answer, you can specify the mechanism by which subtitle tracks are loaded in your mpv.conf file located at `.config/mpv.conf` as explained [here in the mpv manual](https://mpv.io/manual/master/#options-sub-auto). In your case you would add `sub-auto=all`.

Comment: I found that I had to set the filepath to `.config/mpv/mpv.conf` instead of `.config/mpv.conf` (running Xubuntu 20.04 with mpv 0.32.0)

Answer (score 8):

If you use mpv from the terminal you can type `mpv [name of your file] --sub-files=[name of your srt file]`.
Actually you can add a list of srt files type `man mpv` for more info.
Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

In Linux, create a file `mpv.conf` in `~/.config/mpv` and add the following lines:

```
--sub-auto=all 
--sub-file-paths=sub:subtitles:Subs:<any_other_folder_with_subtitle_files>
```

You can add names of folder where subtitles are (could be a subdirectory within the folder of the movie) separated by `:`.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to play an online video from internet using mpv and want to add local subtitle into it.

**for eg.** `mpv --sub-file=subtitle.srt 'Video Url'`
This code is **not** working until **i add the absolute path of subtitle file**

After passing the **absolute path** of the subtitle file in *--sub-file* flag, mpv pick up the subtitle file located in my local pc whose having different name from video file name and streaming online video with it.

**for eg.** `mpv --sub-file=/home/UserName/Desktop/subtitle.srt 'Video Url'`

Hope This Help :]